# Finding a $d$-dimensional hyperplane containing $n$ given points

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm currently trying to find the equation of the $d$-dimensional hyperplane which includes $n$ given points, where $n \ge d$.

Theoretically, it isn't hard - the $d$-dimensional hyperplane is represented as

$$\sum_{i=0}^{d-1} a_i x_i = a_d$$

for some constants $a_0, a_1, \dots, a_d$.

I have $d$ equations in $d+1$ variables (but one is linearly dependent on all others), solve it. Easy.

But, in practice, I'm having quite a hard time implementing it:

If $n > d$, I think I need to remove points, and remain only with $d$ points, in order to be able to solve the equation system and find the $a_i$.

Also, I think I may need to take into account degenerate axes (an axis which is a constant for all given points), and remove those axes before solving the system equation?

I managed to get working code in Python for regular, "normal" cases (I've only tested this in two dimensions for now), but for "hard" cases (like the two dimensional plane $y = -x$, where $a_2 = 0$), my code fails - I'm getting mostly exceptions like:

> Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square

I'll add my code below, though it looks bad. I don't really like it, but I'm trying to make it work before making it look decent.

I'd really appreciate suggestions!

```
def getPlaneFromPoints(points):
    d = len(points[0])
    degenerateAxes = set()
    for j in range(d):
        # If values in that dimension do not change: if this dimension is degenerate
        if np.all(points[:, j] == points[0][j]):
            degenerateAxes.add(j)
    # Remove degenerate axes
    points = points[:, [j not in degenerateAxes for j in range(d)]]
    # Take at most d points, if there are more than d points
    # I think it's necessary in order to solve the equation system?
    points = np.array(points[:d])
    # The result without the degenerate planes
    non_degenerate_result = np.linalg.solve(points, np.ones(len(points)))
    finalResult = np.zeros(d + 1)
    currIndex = 0
    for i in range(d + 1):
        if i == d:
            finalResult[i] = -1
        elif i in degenerateAxes:
            finalResult[i] = 0
        else:
            finalResult[i] = non_degenerate_result[currIndex]
            currIndex += 1
    return finalResult
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31411330/solving-overdetermined-system-in-numpy-when-the-value-of-one-variable-is-already

Comment: You want to solve a (potentially) overdetermined system of linear equations. A solution isn't always possible. You can use a function such as np.linalg.lstsq to find a solution. In order to use np.linalg.solve instead, you need to find a set of linearly independent equations. You cannot just pick an arbitrary subset of points (imagine that one of the points appears twice). That might be what is throwing the solver off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may or may not answer your question, but there's a useful trick you should know.

Sppose you are trying to solve the overdetermined linear system:

$$Ax = b$$

Pre-multiplying both sides of the equation by the transpose of $A$ gives a system that isn't over-determined:

$$A^{T}A x = A^{T}b$$

The solution to this system is the least-squares fit of the original problem. Moreover, $A^{T}A$ is not only square, it's also symmetric and positive definite (assuming it's not singular), so you can use specialised techniques such as [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) or the [conjugate gradient method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method) to solve it.